# force hibernate to reload the hsqldb file before reading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I have following scenario:

- two applications which use the same `in file hsqldb`
- `app1` only writes to/deletes from the `db` and `app2` only reads from it
- `app1` signals (through sending an event) `app2` when the `db` was updated and he should read the new values
- `app2` isn't capable of reading the new values, he sees only the old one

I tried writing with:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
try {
   session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
   session.saveOrUpdate(cluster);
   session.flush();
   return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
   LOG.error("Failed saving cluster {}!", cluster.getName(), e);
   return false;
}
```

an reading:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);

 try {
     return (List<Cluster>) session
              .createCriteria(Cluster.class)
              .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
              .list();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Error while trying to read the clusters from file!", e);
      return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

but sadly this doesn't work.

I also tried closing the connection and then re-opening, but this also doesn't work.

**update[1]:**

I just set:

```
basicDataSource.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED.value())
```

on the side of `app2`, but even so, `app2` isn't capable of reading the updates.

Comment: What table type is used in hsqldb?

Comment: @Evgeny what do you mean by table type? the composition of the table?

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N1023C

Comment: my tables are automatically created by `hibernate`. I took a look at the `sql command` and saw that the tables are creates using `create table`, so it is a `memory table`

Comment: It seems that sever mode is In-Process (Standalone) Mode. Is it so? http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N1013D

Comment: I'm not using `server mode`, there are 2 `in-process (standalone) modes`. One per application and they use the same file (url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB documentstion states:

> Memory tables are the default type when the CREATE TABLE command is used. Their data is held entirely in memory but any change to their structure or contents is written to the .script file. **The script file is read the next time the database is opened, and the MEMORY tables are recreated with all their contents.**

As both application use *standalone* with *memory* tables db state can **not** be synchronized without restart. Theoretically hsqldb instance in `app2` can be forced to reload its state by shutting it down with [`SHUTDOWN` sql command](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#shutdown-section) and consequent starting when new connection is claimed. But it doesn't look like a good solution. Also there is possible conflict if two instances try to save their state to the same file. 


I'd suggest using hsqldb in [Server mode](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N10148) as more appropriate in case of two applications working with one db. Server mode can be started on separate JVM instace or as a part of `app1`.

```
Server server = new Server();

server.setDatabaseName(0, "test");
server.setDatabasePath(0, "file:test");
server.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
server.setErrWriter(new PrintWriter(System.err));
server.start();
```

`app2` will be able to connect using

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test");
```

Comment: thank you, it works! I'm not connecting to the `server` using `DriverManager`, but using `DataSource`, so there wasn't much to change in my code, only adding the `server`